# MacBook as audio source for iPhone USB compatible speakers

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, dock, speakers

Is it possible to output sound from a MacBook via USB to an iPhone/iPod compatible speaker *(the speaker has an USB input that only works with iPhones)*, maybe making the Mac output sound through USB the way the iPhone does?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Bluetooth or AirPlay?

Comment: I find it a bit laggy.

Comment: I am not entirely clear what the question is...1) What's an iPhone/iPod *compatible* speaker?  2) Do you want to play audio to speakers **through** USB or do you want to play sound through your iPod hooked up to speakers?   If you want to do the former, have a look at [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271).  Different question, but relevant answer.

Comment: Edited question: 1) A speaker that has a USB for connecting via USB cable an iPhone and play its music. 2) I want to hear my MacBook through these speakers **through** USB because the miniplug connection has noise when the MacBook is connected to the power outlet.

Comment: Add additional details by **editing the original question**.  Also, can you give an example of these "USB Speakers" that "only" work with iPhones?  I know of no such product.

Comment: I clarified in the comment and in the original question that the speaker has an USB input, they're not "USB speakers". There are a lot of products which provide the dock connector or alternatively an USB but in the same way are designed for iPhone or iPod devices, mostly portable speakers, soundbars, receivers and of course, my [Nocs NS2](http://nocs.se/products/ns2-air-monitors-v2) speakers.

Answer (score 1):

You can output Mac sound via USB by changing the settings in Sound. Connect the USB speaker, then open System Preferences. Select Sound. There are three 'tabs' in this window: Sound Effects, Output, Input. Select Output. You may see your speakers, or perhaps "USB audio CODEC". Choose either one.  Sound will come out of the USB speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Without the devices to test, it's hard to say. 
I do know that iPhones have a specific signal they send - for example, in my truck, there's a USB port to play music that only works with iPhones and iPod Touch devices - Android and even my MacBook read as unsupported devices.

It would be able to connect via Bluetooth though - out of the options you mentioned, that may be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Sending audio over USB is certainly possible, there are USB-based headsets on the market which require exactly that. Whether a given speaker supports this depends on the model though, please consult the manual (or contact the vendor).