# Macbook pro 2018 - microphone shown as 1 input in Audio MIDI setup

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone

Microphone quality is really poor in my Macbook pro 2018 (15 inch) when I compare it to Macbook pro 2016.

When I enter Audio MIDI Setup on Macbook pro 2018 I see (sorry for polish lamguage):
[image]

However in Macbook pro 2016 it was:

[image]

Is it OK for my Macbook pro 2018 (15 inch) to have only 1-in ?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) The `1 in / 0 outs` doesn't necessarily indicate a hardware problem, but we do need more information about your setup. Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/336061/edit) your question to include a screenshot of the Audio Devices window within Audio Midi Setup? Make sure the Microphone option is highlighted in the left sidebar when you take the screenshot. This will help us clarify your configuration and if you have any other devices and/or software that's interacting with your audio inputs/outputs.

Comment: I will include screenshot in a few hours. Thanks for tip :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems normal.

Looking at the tech specs for both the [2016 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP749?locale=en_US) and the [2018 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776?locale=en_US), you will see under the "Audio" section, that they have 3 microphones and 2 microphones respectively.

So, it appears that the 2018 model has one less microphone channel and this is what you're seeing.  As for audio input, I would look at getting a quality [USB audio DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) instead of using the built in microphones

Comment: Both your links show MacBook pro 2016 spec for me. However on https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776?locale=en_US I see audio with three microphones for MacBook pro 2018

Comment: Sorry about that...fixed the link.  Copy/Paste goof on my part.

Comment: Tech specs say that both MacBooks have three microphones, right? So why difference in microphone channels?

Comment: No.  One has two (2018), the other has three(2016).