# External microphone with mid-2012 Macbook Air

Tags: microphone

I cannot get any of my external microphones to work with my
mid-2012 MacBook Air (which runs Arch Linux).  Neither the
four-pin-jack headphone that comes with iPhones, nor the Beoplay
H9i (three pins).  It is clear in `pavucontrol` that only the
internal microphone is listened to.  Output works.  Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you are using a [non-Apple headphone](https://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans) so the Mic pin is in the wrong location on the TRRS jack

My advice is to avoid using the built in a jack and use a quality USB microphone or at least a [quality DAC that accepts standard headphone input](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271)  I’ve personally gotten better audio quality going the USB route (no pops or hums) versus the built in connector.