# How to remove aux jack from Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

Recently I've got an aux jack stuck in the headphone port of my Macbook Pro 2015. (see photo below)

[image: aux jack]

The entire jack broke off, as opposed to just the tip which is usually what happens for most. The jack is really wedged in as far as it will go and it's also at an angle.

I've tried using a bit of super glue and sticking the end of the jack back on to the old cable and then pulling it, but that didn't work and I think there might even be some super glue in the port now.

Ive tried using pliars to get it out, but that doesn't work because there is hardly anything for it to grip on to.

Would anyone know how to deal with this please? Any advice would be really appreciated!

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the port has super glue in it, there isn’t anything you can do to remove the broken piece other than take it in for service and have the port replaced.

The audio jack is somewhat hollow, but it does have a conductor in the center.  It may have been possible to push a “tinned” piece of wire into the jack and then heat The wire so the solder will weld the wire to the jack allowing you to pull it out.  You’ll need a soldering iron and some soldering skills to do this.

Alternately, you may be able to open the Mac, and from the back of the socket, use a stiff piece of wire to push it out of the jack.

However, most likely, the only solution would be unsolder the jack from the logic board and solder on a new one. You’ll have to take in in unless you have surface mount PCB rework skills and tools.    Now, that’s going to be expensive, so if you opt to not do this and go for a workaround, you”ll either need to use Bluetooth speakers or a [USB DAC (Digital Audio Converter)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) to give you back physical input and output connections.

Comment: Actually "Super Glue" *does* have a solvent. Acetone will usually (depending on the bonding surfaces) dissolve Cyanoacrylate (Super glue) Adhesive. But that looks like it was jammed into the port and may be difficult to remove without damaging the MacBook or opening it to push it out from the inside. @Allan has got the general idea, this is a difficult repair, at best.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened my MacBook Air M1 2020... I had something in the AUX port as well. The AUX 'board' is very easy to disassemble, what I did. Once out of the Macbook it's more easy to remove things out of the AUX port. Maybe it's possible to remove the jack plug piece with the help of a little drill like in a DREMEL tool. Try to drill a little hole in the jack plug piece and then screw a tiny little screw in it so you can pull the piece out. For me it worked. If not, just buy a new AUX 'board' an everything is OK. Good Luck!